# Got errors with ONBUILD options (Docker toolbox in Windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, npm

I have a problem with my Docker on Windows (through Docker Toolbox). May be someone can help.

**My Dockerfile without ONBUILD:**

```
FROM node:5.9.1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Working ok (**docker build -t test .** and start it: **docker run -it --rm --name testrun test**)
But if i change Dockerfile to ONBUILD option:

```
FROM node:5.9.1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ONBUILD COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
ONBUILD RUN npm install
ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
EXPOSE 3000
```

I get an errors:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.7.3
npm info using node@v5.9.1
npm ERR! Linux 4.1.19-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.js
on'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.js
on'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
```

Whats im doing wrong? (im novice in Docker :) ). Maybe I'm wrong use ONBUILD? But like anything not clear there is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Dockerfile man page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild):

> The `ONBUILD` instruction adds to the image a trigger instruction to be executed at a later time, **when the image is used as the base for another build**.

Since you are not using another image starting with "`FROM test`", those instruction are never executed, meaning the `test` image does not include what those commands were supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you left out some details in your question, you're not using `ONBUILD` correctly.

The `ONBUILD` option is to queue commands to run in a subsequent build. The commands you specified above wouldn't be executed unless you wrapped your image by including it in the `FROM` reference in another Dockerfile.

Please see the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild) on this subject for additional information.